# Export and import all SharedPreferences to a file

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my android app I have different types of data (booleans, numbers and strings) in two SharedPreference files: *com.package.index* and *com.package.storage*.
The question is, How it is possible to entirely export both SharedPreference files to an external file and import it back? (This is essential for backup and migration between devices), thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
private final SharedPreferences _settings;
/**
 * Serialize all preferences into an output stream
 * @param os OutputStream to write to
 * @return True iff successful
 */
public boolean serialize(final @NonNull OutputStream os) {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(_settings.getAll());
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error serializing preferences", BuildConfig.DEBUG ? e : null);
        return false;
    } finally {
        Utils.closeQuietly(oos, os);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Read all preferences from an input stream.
 * Schedules a full preference clean, then deserializes the options present in the given stream.
 * If the given object contains an unknown class, the deserialization is aborted and the underlying
 * preferences are not changed by this method
 * @param is Input stream to load the preferences from
 * @return True iff the new values were successfully written to persistent storage
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
public boolean deserialize(final @NonNull InputStream is) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Map<String, Object> map = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        map = (Map) ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error deserializing preferences", BuildConfig.DEBUG ? e : null);
        return false;
    } finally {
        Utils.closeQuietly(ois, is);
    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _settings.edit();
    editor.clear();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : map.entrySet()) {
        // Unfortunately, the editor only provides typed setters
        if (e.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
            editor.putBoolean(e.getKey(), (Boolean)e.getValue());
        } else if (e.getValue() instanceof String) {
            editor.putString(e.getKey(), (String)e.getValue());
        } else if (e.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
            editor.putInt(e.getKey(), (int)e.getValue());
        } else if (e.getValue() instanceof Float) {
            editor.putFloat(e.getKey(), (float)e.getValue());
        } else if (e.getValue() instanceof Long) {
            editor.putLong(e.getKey(), (Long) e.getValue());
        } else if (e.getValue() instanceof Set) {
            editor.putStringSet(e.getKey(), (Set<String>) e.getValue());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type " + e.getValue().getClass().getName() + " is unknown");
        }
    }
    return editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` has a [`getAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()) method that you can use to retrieve all of the values in a given `SharedPreferences`. You can then use that to serialize the values in your external file however you wish.

Note that on Android 6.0 (API 23) and above, [Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) will automatically backup shared preferences files for you.